# Gcloud pull command to search for a particular record

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

We are using the topic to post a ID to transmit the record to the other application and i tried to use this command to validate whether the source system posted the record or not .But it returns the records which i dont need.

Is their any value to add the search command to search for a particular record

gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull --limit=100  --format=json | jq -r .[].message.data | base64 -d

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pull a particular message. You also want to make sure that you aren't using the gcloud tool on the same subscription as your other application. Otherwise, pulling from gcloud may introduce a delay for your application receiving any messages that gcloud managed to display.

If you need to verify that particular messages got published, the only thing you could do is set up a second subscription and then write a subscriber client that receives all of the messages and looks for the one you want. Just make sure you create the subscription before the message is published in order to ensure it will be received.

Comment: Even after creating a second subscription ,can't we filter out to search for a specific record by using filter expression? like --filter="zone ~ us AND -machineType:f1-micro"

Comment: If you have attributes, then you could probably narrow it down with filters, yes. However, note that you'd need to know the filter you want to use before the message was published since the subscription must exist first for it to receive the message.

Comment: Yes i used the filter but am getting "The following filter keys were not present in any resource : Messagebody" message

Comment: It sounds like you are using the gcloud filter feature and not Pub/Sub's filter feature. You need to use the `--message-filter` flag to create a subscription with a Pub/Sub filter.

Comment: Am getting unrecognized arguments error while using this expression ---              
 gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull --message-filter="body.visit_id~81cafe62-1327-4754-bbbf-b9cc50b66060" p360-schedule_event-ops --project=eds-pubsub-qa-tets --format="json" | jq -r .[].message.data  |base64 -d
ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.subscriptions.pull) unrecognized arguments: --message-filter=body.visit_id~81cafe62-1327-4754-bbbf-b9cc50b66060 (did you mean '--filter'?)

Comment: It's not on the pull command. It is on the create command.